# Angular *ngFor on different divs

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-flex-layout

I have a markup using material flex in angular 4 project which looks like this.

```
<div fxLayout="row">
  <div fxFlex="65">
    
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="35">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

And I have an array of elements like this:

```
public array: [object] = [
    {
        firstName: 'value',
        lastName: 'value'
    },
    {
        firstName: 'value',
        lastName: 'value'
    },
    {
        firstName: 'value',
        lastName: 'value'
    },
    {
        firstName: 'value',
        lastName: 'value'
    },
    {
        firstName: 'value',
        lastName: 'value'
    },
];
```

I want to loop through this array and fill half of all elements in 65% div and the rest of elements in 35% div. How to do it with `*ngFor` directive correctly? Now I have solution like this. But it looks horrible and not readable.

```
    <div fxLayout="row">
      <div fxFlex="65">
        <div *ngFor="let item of array; let i = index">
          <div *ngIf="i < 3">
            <p>{{ item.firstName }}</p>
            <p>{{ item.lastName }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div fxFlex="35">
        <div *ngFor="let item of array; let i = index">
          <div *ngIf="i >= 3">
            <p>{{ item.firstName }}</p>
            <p>{{ item.lastName }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Is there any other solutions to do that?
I also tried using `<template>` element. But my tries failed.
Please help me with that!

Comment: Is the number of elements fixed and known, or should the layout adapt to any number of elements?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Now, the array is fixed and has 14 items. But it could be more in future.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [SlicePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe), as shown in [**this plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/aZKr4oIRsEvjxLoNlzZU?p=preview).

```
<div fxLayout="row">
    <div fxFlex="65">
        <div *ngFor="let item of array | slice:0:half">
            <p>{{ item.firstName }}</p>
            <p>{{ item.lastName }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="35">
        <div *ngFor="let item of array | slice:half">
            <p>{{ item.firstName }}</p>
            <p>{{ item.lastName }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `half` property would be defined in the component class:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class Component1 {
    public array: [object] = [
        {
            firstName: 'first1',
            lastName: 'last1'
        },
        {
            firstName: 'first2',
            lastName: 'last2'
        },
        ...
    ];
    public get half(): number {
        return Math.ceil(this.array.length / 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice approach. Thanks!

Comment: Nice answer @ConnorsFan

Answer (score 1):

Just slice the array in the `*ngFor`:

```
<div fxFlex="65">
    <div *ngFor="let item of array.slice(0, array.length / 2)">
        <p>{{ item.firstName }}</p>
        <p>{{ item.lastName }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div fxFlex="35">
    <div *ngFor="let item of array.slice(array.length / 2, array.length)">
        <p>{{ item.firstName }}</p>
        <p>{{ item.lastName }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div fxLayout="row">
      <div fxFlex="65">
        <div *ngFor="let item of array.slice(0,array.length/2)">

            <p>{{ item.firstName }}</p>
            <p>{{ item.lastName }}</p>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div fxFlex="35">
        <div *ngFor="let item of array.slice(array.length/2)">

            <p>{{ item.firstName }}</p>
            <p>{{ item.lastName }}</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Use [ ... ].slice()

> for first half slice(0, half)
>
> for second half slice(half)